# How to make comparator work correctly, now it gives wrong length of strings

Tags: java

I have these words in a txt file:

jaguar chimpanzee bison whale
marmot bison lemur panther camel lizard wolf bear
gecko
mongoose leopard sable sable dingo whale jaguar
rat lemur lemur gorilla zebra tortoise
asp lion tapir tortoise gorilla cheetah bison marten
marmot cheetah camel
snake marmot
zebra asp cheetah lizard gecko gorilla asp lion tortoise
kangaroo whale penguin yak cheetah mouse panther

I need to find the 3 longest words and put it in a map.
Comparator class is:

```
private static class SortByValue implements Comparator<String>{

    public SortByValue(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> map;

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

        return (map.get(o1) >= map.get(o2)) ? -1 : ((map.get(o1) == map.get(o2)) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

The output after all methods I don't show here should be (the first longest strings in array):

```
chimpanzee ==> 10

mongoose ==> 8

tortoise ==> 8
```

But comparator makes it (wrong, cant pass exam):

```
chimpanzee ==> 10

tortoise ==> 8

kangaroo ==> 8
```

Where is the mistake? Help please

Comment: Is your issue that "mongoose" and "tortoise" and "kangaroo" are in the wrong order, despite being the same length? You lose the stability of the order when you put the strings in a hashmap. Why is the map necessary?

Comment: @khelwood yes, first there goes "mongoose" but comparator can't see it and puts "tortoise" first, don't know why. After, I iterate on an String []arr field full of these words and put only 3 longest words in a hashmap in a loop cycle. HashMap value is the length of these words. All the words are in a right order in this array

Comment: Skip the map. Just sort the words using length directly and then take the top three.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can make a Comparator that sorts strings by length, longest first:

```
private static class SortByValue implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2.length(), o1.length());
    }
}
```

Applied to your list of strings, the first 3 words that come out will be  chimpanzee, mongoose, tortoise.

Comment: Thanks! But I put an instance of this comparator class into a TreeMap, after this I go into a loop and iterate on String [] arr field of main class, there I put in a simple<String, Integer> HashMap strings and length of this words and after that I put simple hashmap object in a TreeMap using .putAll() method.
Should I edit my question so you could see it? I have not only length problems but also frequencies of these words and dublicates and i use TreeMap everywhere

Comment: That sounds like a separate question: not related to sorting a list of strings according to length. You should post it as a separate question. It's hard to see how the TreeMap and HashMap that you describe relate to each other

Comment: For example, HashMap is not even Comparable, what are you doing putting HashMap objects into TreeMap? I doubt the comment box has enough space for the explanation